# Ignite Server encounters IgniteDataIntegrityViolationException when trying to join cluster

Tags: java, kubernetes, ignite

We are using Ignite 2.15 in kubernetes with persistence enabled and have encountered an error where if the Ignite server nodes crash and restart they cannot rejoin the cluster with the error bellow.

The issue seems similar to [this error](https://www.mail-archive.com/user@ignite.apache.org/msg22922.html).

Is there a way to fix this issue without loss of data?

```
[13:30:41,467][SEVERE][main][IgniteKernal] Got exception while starting (will rollback startup routine).
        class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to read WAL record at position: 387902845, size: 536867006, expectedPtr: WALPointer [idx=2727, fileOff=387902845, len=0]
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.AbstractWalRecordsIterator.handleRecordException(AbstractWalRecordsIterator.java:327)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileWriteAheadLogManager$RecordsIterator.handleRecordException(FileWriteAheadLogManager.java:3206)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.AbstractWalRecordsIterator.advanceRecord(AbstractWalRecordsIterator.java:291)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.AbstractWalRecordsIterator.advance(AbstractWalRecordsIterator.java:176)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.AbstractWalRecordsIterator.onNext(AbstractWalRecordsIterator.java:135)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.AbstractWalRecordsIterator.onNext(AbstractWalRecordsIterator.java:52)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridCloseableIteratorAdapter.nextX(GridCloseableIteratorAdapter.java:44)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager$RestoreStateContext.next(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:3427)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager$RestoreBinaryState.next(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:3571)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.performBinaryMemoryRestore(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:2186)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.readMetastore(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:865)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.notifyMetaStorageSubscribersOnReadyForRead(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:3094)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1120)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1725)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1647)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1089)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:983)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:889)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:808)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:678)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:647)
                at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:325)
                at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:365)
        Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to read WAL record at position: 387902845, size: 536867006, expectedPtr: WALPointer [idx=2727, fileOff=387902845, len=0]
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.serializer.RecordV1Serializer.readWithCrc(RecordV1Serializer.java:396)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.serializer.RecordV2Serializer.readRecord(RecordV2Serializer.java:249)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.AbstractWalRecordsIterator.advanceRecord(AbstractWalRecordsIterator.java:273)
                ... 20 more
        Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.crc.IgniteDataIntegrityViolationException: val: 1872793019 writtenCrc: 2013265920
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.io.FileInput$Crc32CheckingFileInput.close(FileInput.java:105)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.serializer.RecordV1Serializer.readWithCrc(RecordV1Serializer.java:381)
                ... 22 more
```

Comment: At first glance this one doesn't look similar to the issue from the user list. It's not even about "joining", this node can't start because of local issues, prior to joining procedures. In general it's a complex topic, it's almost impossible to say about the possibility of recovery without analysis of the original failure. Could you share logs prior to the node failure? I'd say it doesn't look normal, something happened that's pretty unusual and it was totally unexpected by an Ignite node.